# How to debug a published native app (C++)?

Tags: android, debugging, google-play, publishing

I need to publish an app that is made with QT/C++ in Google Play. While developing and testing beta in Google Play, I used a debug version and lots of logs to spot bugs. I either connected to the testers' devices via adb or asked them to send me a log that was stored in system "Download" directory. I am worried about several issues if my app is published:

1. I feel like a release version must be published. Will I get core dump for a native app in google play console for release version? If I do, I am afraid it will be useless without debug information.
2. Is publishing debug version a bad idea? Is there any obfuscation support for native code or binaries? If so, will it help me to still get core dump and/or debug logs while preventing the app from being reverse engineered?
3. I am thinking about logging to a file and catching SIGSEGV, sending a log file to our server using http POST request. What drawbacks/issues do you see with this solution?
4. What are other technics would you advise to use that will help to track down and fix issues in a published app?

Comment: YOu cannot publish a  debug version of your app

Comment: @jsRook I just want to clarify, are you sure I can not build a release version of the app with debug versions of native libraries inside? Because I am pretty sure I can build it and I might have done this in beta testing, though not sure.

Comment: Try to generate a signed version of your app and then publish it in play console if after processing it accept then means you can publish it if  not then it does not

Comment: Not sure about libraries but your app should not be a debug version it sholud be signed

Answer (score 0):

You can use other techniques or features like firebase or fabric for crash reporting and other things no need to send logs, Whenever any crash occur they will provide logs also

For better performance disable all logs in production build

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: 1 :** Yes you can do this by changing all debug logs  to error logs (Log.d() -> Log.e() ). because debug logs are not visible in Release build but you can see error logs in any variant.

**Solution 2:** You can use Fabric  and see all your logs to Fabric account. This can be done by using its [Answer module](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/overview.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but solution 1 is not an option, since this is a native app and I use native logging not Android's `Log.d()`. And I don't think that it is good to have debug info a errors. I will check out Fabric